# Getting Facebook APP info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get parse information about the App that I own? that is to say, that I know the App Id, secret Id and all the relevant information. Does the API provide a way to, say, get the number of users using my app? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, you need to use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and query [this table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/).

Comment: Hm. Actually this table doesn't provide the total number of users.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get total number of users. You can get number of monthly active users, which is what FB presents as count of users, I suppose.

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to find a way to get more precise data.